# Как запретить добавлять пробелы в название файлов/папок(используется ESLint и react)?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, linter

Как запретить добавлять пробелы в название файлов/папок(используется ESLint и react)?
Например что бы нельзя было назвать файл/папку "List Item"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать использовать плагин `eslint-plugin-folders`:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-folders